# qTip: How to get the tip's outer div?

Tags: javascript, qtip

I have examined the [API](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/) carefully but I have not found the way to do it.

What I need is: I have a link to qtip object. The baloon tip itself has the container div, all the stuff (title, content, borders) is inside. How can I get that outer div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inspecting the DOM, it looks like all of the qTip elements are wrapped in one `div` with a class of `qtip`.

You should be able to use the [jQuery parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to select the outermost container from your reference. Assuming your reference is called `tip`:

```
var outer = tip.parent('.qtip');
```

Comment: Great! But why not `tip.find('.qtip')`?

Comment: `find` selects descendants (nested elements), and it sounds like you want to select a parent element. See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/find/